# Wordpress register custom menu

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a menu in header of my custom website and I want to register this menu on Wordpress `functions.php` file and use it in `header.php` file.

Custom menu html code:

```html
<div id="top-nav-right-items" class="pull-right top-links">
  <ul class="list-inline">
    <li><a href="">فروشگاه</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-external-link-square"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">حساب کاربری</span> <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <li><a target="_blank" title="" href="">آیتم 1</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" title="" href="">آیتم 2</a></li>
        <li><a target="_blank" title="" href="">آیتم 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="">سبد خرید</a></li>
    <li><a href="">تسویه حساب</a></li>
    <li><a href="">درباره ما</a></li>
    <li><a href="">تماس با ما</a></li>
  </ul>


</div>
<!-- #top-nav-right-items -->
```

I know how to register this menu in `functions.php` file but I don't know how to show the custom menu in my wordpress site.

```
<?php

function register_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('top-menu',__( 'TOP MENU' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_menu' );

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render your menu in the template file with the [`wp_nav_menu()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) function.

In it’s simplest form it could be invoked like this:

```
wp_nav_menu(array (
    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
));
```

For basic customization you could change the [default parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#parameters) listed in the array. However, this is quite limited, as you can change only a couple of things like `container_class` and `menu_class` with simple changes.
There is though the `walker` parameter, which accepts a [`Walker`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/Walker) instance. By default this is set to [`Walker_Nav_Menu`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src//wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php#L0), and this is the class that effectively handles the rendering of the menu. For the deepest customization, you could extend this class and set the new class as the `walker` parameter. This gives you full control over the menu.

In case you do not want to go this deep though, there are still some filters available to alter how the menu is rendered. You can spot these filters in the source code of the `Walker_Nav_Menu` too.
These filters are [`nav_menu_submenu_css_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_submenu_css_class/), `nav_menu_item_args`, `nav_menu_css_class`, `nav_menu_item_id`, `nav_menu_link_attributes`, `nav_menu_item_title` and `walker_nav_menu_start_el`.

So for example, to add new css classes to the sub-menus, you could code something like as follows:

```
add_filter('nav_menu_submenu_css_class', function ($classes, $args, $depth) {
    $classes[] = 'dropdown-menu';
    $classes[] = 'dropdown-menu-right';

    return $classes;
}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: how i can define a style or a class for sub-menu item in wp_nav_menu() function? like class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right"?

Comment: Extended my answer, and included sub-menu class customization too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "menu_class" or "container_class" parameter.

```
wp_nav_menu(array (
    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
    'menu_class' => 'class_name',
));
```

You can check the [wordpress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) for all available parameter for this function.

Edit: The menu_class parameter will be applied to the **ul**.

Answer (score 0):

```
function register_my_menus(){
register_nav_menus(
array(
'primary-menu'=>__('Primary Menu'),
'footer-menu'=>__('Footer Menu'),
'additional-menu'=>__('Additional Menu')
)
);
}
add_action('init','register_my_menus');
```